# Launching multiple scripts without waiting the end of the previous using anacron

Tags: startup, anacron

On a small server, I would like to launch a selenium webdriver and a python script which will use the selenium webdriver consecutively at boot, without waiting the end of the other (of course).

I therefore added the following lines to my `/etc/anacrontab`:

```
@daily  1       webdriver       java -jar ~/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar &
@daily  2       wifi_manager    ~/script.py &
```

By doing this, the two processes are however terminated:

```
Jun 24 01:09:51 david anacron[441]: Job `webdriver' started
Jun 24 01:09:51 david anacron[441]: Job `webdriver' terminated
Jun 24 01:10:51 david anacron[441]: Job `wifi_manager' started
Jun 24 01:10:51 david anacron[441]: Job `wifi_manager' terminated
```

How should I start them, in order to have them running permanently?

---

EDIT:
I now have:

```
@daily  1       wifi_manager    bash -c '$dir/start_driver.sh & (sleep 30 && $dir/dis-enable_wifi.py) &'
```

But I still get:
Jun 24 14:02:56 david anacron[444]: Job `wifi_manager' started
Jun 24 14:02:56 david anacron[444]: Job`wifi_manager' terminated

The `start_driver.sh` consists in:

```
cd $dir # needed in order to have log saved there...
nohup java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar &
```

Basically, I have to start the selenium webdriver, wait until it is ready and then run the python script for the whole day.

If I run the command I put in the anacrontab from terminal it just works fine.

Comment: Consider starting a shell and running those scripts in background, something like `bash -c '/home/user/script.py & another_script.sh &'`

Comment: What is the absolute location of the scripts? it's rarely a good idea to rely on `~` inside (ana)crontabs

Comment: @steeldriver I just faked its location in order to avoid unnecessarily long lines, it is actually not ~.

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy You're right. This is definitely the solution I was pointing to. So late at night I didn't realized :-! Thanks

Comment: I've turned my comment into an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider starting a shell and running those scripts in background, something like

```
 bash -c '/home/user/script.py & another_script.sh &'
```

Comment: Thanks, I unfortunately still have some problems (see edit in my post). Do you have an idea on what is causing the problem?